# Generate data SQL by value data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have data table like this

```
+----+---------+--------+
| id |  name   | values |
+----+---------+--------+
|  1 | Budi    |      4 |
|  2 | sanjaya |      3 |
|  3 | Dadang  |      2 |
+----+---------+--------+
```

I want to select the data like this

```
+----+---------+--------+--------+
| id |  name   | values | number |
+----+---------+--------+--------+
|  1 | Budi    |      4 |      1 |
|  1 | Budi    |      4 |      2 |
|  1 | Budi    |      4 |      3 |
|  1 | Budi    |      4 |      4 |
|  2 | sanjaya |      3 |      1 |
|  2 | sanjaya |      3 |      2 |
|  2 | sanjaya |      3 |      3 |
|  3 | Dadang  |      2 |      1 |
|  3 | Dadang  |      2 |      2 |
+----+---------+--------+--------+
```

number can generate by values rows

Comment: please show the query that you tried

Comment: this easily achieve with `recursive cte`. Please have a look at the documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#guidelines-for-defining-and-using-recursive-common-table-expressions

Comment: thanks, i will try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DECLARE @temp TABLE
( 
    [id] int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    [name] varchar(10),
    [values] int
)
INSERT INTO @temp VALUES(1, 'Budi', 4)
INSERT INTO @temp VALUES(2, 'sanjaya', 3)
INSERT INTO @temp VALUES(3, 'Dadang', 2)

;WITH cte([id], [name], [values], [number]) AS   
(  
    SELECT [id], [name], [values], 1 AS [number]
    FROM @temp
    UNION ALL  
    SELECT cte.[id], cte.[name], cte.[values], cte.[number] + 1 AS [number]
    FROM cte
    WHERE cte.[number] < cte.[values]
)
SELECT * FROM cte ORDER BY [id], [number]
```

Comment: Read about why you don't want to use Recursive CTEs at the following URL.  https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/hidden-rbar-counting-with-recursive-ctes

Comment: THanks @JeffModen work, i never hear recursive cte, and this can solved my problem, thanks very much

Comment: It solved the functional aspect... rCTEs don't look like a performance problem for smaller rowsets but still is.  They're fraught with totally unnecessary CPU and Memory I/U resource usage wastes.  Consider using the code that I posted, which has no such problems.

Answer (score 4):

@Dhanang2112 ,

I appreciate you trying to format the data for your example but, if you create readily consumable data, you'll get far better answers and you'll get them much more quickly.

Here's your data in a readily consumable format... namely code...

```
 SELECT v.*
   INTO #TestTable
   FROM (VALUES
         (1,'Budi'   ,4)
        ,(2,'sanjaya',3)
        ,(3,'Dadang' ,2)
        ) v (id,name,[values])
;
```

I wouldn't use a Recursive CTE ("rCTE" from here on) because even a well formed WHILE loop can beat them and use fewer resources in the process.  If you want to know more about the "Hidden RBAR" of rCTEs, please see the following article because it's much too long to explain here.

https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/hidden-rbar-counting-with-recursive-ctes

Instead, we'll use Itzik Ben-Gan's method of "Cascading CTEs" (my name for his technique and "cCTE" from here on).  The following function is my favorite method because it makes a lot of things, like your given problem, a whole lot easier.  If your DBA objects, have them read the header.  It's NOT either a slow scalar function or mTVF (Multi-statement Table Valued Function).  It's a high performance iTVF (Inline table Valued Function).  Most of it is comments.

```
 CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fnTally] --Rev 04
/**********************************************************************************************************************
 Purpose:
 Return a column of BIGINTs from @ZeroOrOne up to and including @MaxN with a max value of 10 Quadrillion.

 Usage:
--===== Syntax example
 SELECT t.N
   FROM dbo.fnTally(@ZeroOrOne,@MaxN) t
;
 @ZeroOrOne will return a 1 for any number other than 0 and a 0 for a 0.
 @MaxN has an operation domain from 0 to 4,294,967,296.

 Please see the following notes for other important information


 Notes:
 1. This code works for SQL Server 2008 and up.
 2. Based on Itzik Ben-Gan's cascading CTE (cCTE) method for creating a "readless" Tally Table source of BIGINTs.
    Refer to the following URL for how it works.
    https://www.itprotoday.com/sql-server/virtual-auxiliary-table-numbers
 3. To start a sequence at 0, @ZeroOrOne must be 0. Any other value that's convertable to the BIT data-type
    will cause the sequence to start at 1.
 4. If @ZeroOrOne = 1 and @MaxN = 0, no rows will be returned.
 5. If @MaxN is negative or NULL, a "TOP" error will be returned.
 6. @MaxN must be a positive number from >= the value of @ZeroOrOne up to and including 4,294,967,296. If a larger
    number is used, the function will silently truncate after that max. If you actually need a sequence with that many
    or more values, you should consider using a different tool. ;-)
 7. There will be a substantial reduction in performance if "N" is sorted in descending order.  If a descending sort is
    required, use code similar to the following. Performance will decrease by about 27% but it's still very fast 
    especially compared with just doing a simple descending sort on "N", which is about 20 times slower.
    If @ZeroOrOne is a 0, in this case, remove the "+1" from the code.

    DECLARE @MaxN BIGINT; 
     SELECT @MaxN = 1000;
     SELECT DescendingN = @MaxN-N+1 
       FROM dbo.fnTally(1,@MaxN);

 8. There is no performance penalty for sorting "N" in ascending order because the output is implicity sorted by
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
 9. This will return 1-10,000,000 to a bit-bucket variable in about 986ms.
    This will return 0-10,000,000 to a bit-bucket variable in about 1091ms.
    This will return 1-4,294,967,296 to a bit-bucket variable in about 9:12( mi:ss).

 Revision History:
 Rev 00 - Unknown     - Jeff Moden 
        - Initial creation with error handling for @MaxN.
 Rev 01 - 09 Feb 2013 - Jeff Moden 
        - Modified to start at 0 or 1.
 Rev 02 - 16 May 2013 - Jeff Moden 
        - Removed error handling for @MaxN because of exceptional cases.
 Rev 03 - 07 Sep 2013 - Jeff Moden 
        - Change the max for @MaxN from 10 Billion to 10 Quadrillion to support an experiment. 
          This will also make it much more difficult for someone to actually get silent truncation in the future.
 Rev 04 - 04 Aug 2019 - Jeff Moden
        - Enhance performance by making the first CTE provide 256 values instead of 10, which limits the number of
          CrossJoins to just 2. Notice that this changes the maximum range of values to "just" 4,294,967,296, which
          is the entire range for INT and just happens to be an even power of 256. Because of the use of the VALUES
          clause, this code is "only" compatible with SQLServer 2008 and above.
        - Update old link from "SQLMag" to "ITPro". Same famous original article, just a different link because they
          changed the name of the company (twice, actually).
        - Update the flower box notes with the other changes.
**********************************************************************************************************************/
        (@ZeroOrOne BIT, @MaxN BIGINT)
RETURNS TABLE WITH SCHEMABINDING AS 
 RETURN WITH
  H2(N) AS ( SELECT 1 
               FROM (VALUES
                     (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)
                    ,(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)
                    ,(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)
                    ,(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)
                    ,(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)
                    ,(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)
                    ,(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)
                    ,(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)
                    ,(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)
                    ,(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)
                    ,(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)
                    ,(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)
                    ,(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)
                    ,(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)
                    ,(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)
                    ,(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)
                    )V(N))            --16^2 or 256 rows
, H4(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM H2 a, H2 b) --16^4 or 65,536 rows
, H8(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM H4 a, H4 b) --16^8 or 4,294,967,296 rows
            SELECT N = 0 WHERE @ZeroOrOne = 0 UNION ALL
            SELECT TOP(@MaxN)
                   N = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY N)
              FROM H8
;
```

And, now it's super easy and very fast to solve problems like yours.  Here's the code.

```
--===== The problem becomes child's play.
 SELECT tt.id ,tt.name, tt.[values], Numbers = t.N
   FROM ATestTable tt
  CROSS APPLY dbo.fnTally(1, tt.[values]) t
  ORDER BY tt.id, t.N
;
```

Here's the result...

[image: Results]

p.s.  I forgot to mention that this is what is known as "Relational Multiplication".  Basically, it's the result of a Cross Join between the values produced by the function for each row and the content of each row.

Comment: Although I don't really understand the theory behind yet, I tried your solution and it actually has better performance, thanks for sharing.

Comment: Thank you for the kind feedback.  That was the whole aim... performance... which is secondary only to proper functionality and it's a pretty close second.

Comment: Glad to see your name come up, I've learnt a lot from you over many years on SSC and other forums. I've seen an interesting variation on Itzik's trick recently in the dbt codebase: https://github.com/fishtown-analytics/dbt-utils/blob/master/macros/sql/generate_series.sql The template generates an equivalent to a bit shift (using pow) where the column from each CTE represents the bits. It also "right-sizes" the number of cross joins required (at build time) based on fitting the upper limit into a quick search over powers of 2. It's fast on Postgres, I don't have access to SQL Server to test it.

Comment: Thank for the kind feedback and the pointer to the dbt trick.  I don't want to hi-jack this thread on a conversation about dbt (and so won't) but that's some interesting code.  Thanks for posting the link.

Comment: just thinking the same thing...."I've learnt a lot from you over many years on SSC"

Comment: Thank you, as well.  I'm humbled by both your comments.